# Changing Django form property 'required' by bool in template

Tags: django

I'm trying to have the option for an admin to make fields required or not for a user.

My form looks like this.

```
class StudentDetailForm(MyForm):
    first_name = fields.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = fields.CharField(required=True)
    date_of_birth = MyDateField(required=True, widget=MyDateInput(attrs{'class': 'dobpicker'}))
    id_number2 = fields.CharField(required=True, label='PPS Number')
    note = fields.CharField(required=False,
          widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': '25', 'rows': '2'}))


class Meta:
    model = Person
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'id_number2', 'gender', 'note']
```

etc...

This is how I tried to changed the required field. It loops through all the fields and presents tick boxes for visible or required on the admin page.

Then each is presented on the form page with a required or not value.

```
student_form = StudentDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None)
mother_form = ParentDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None, prefix='g1', instance=mother)
father_form = ParentDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None, prefix='g2', instance=father)
family_form = FamilyDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None)

# student_form, mother_form, father_form, family_form = get_web_intake_forms(school, request.POST or None, requestpps)

for name, value in webfields.items():
    if not value['visible']:
        # name is actual name plus : plus a number
        # split up to name and number
        bits = name.split(':')
        fname = bits[0]
        formnum = bits[1]
        if formnum == '1':
            del student_form.fields[fname]
        elif formnum == '2':
            del mother_form.fields[fname]
        elif formnum == '3':
            del father_form.fields[fname]
        elif formnum == '4':
            del family_form.fields[fname]

    elif value['required']:
        # name is actual name plus : plus a number
        # split up to name and number
        bits = name.split(':')
        fname = bits[0]
        formnum = bits[1]
        if formnum == '1':
            student_form.base_fields[fname].required = True
        elif formnum == '2':
            mother_form.fields[fname].required = True
        elif formnum == '3':
            father_form.fields[fname].required = True
        elif formnum == '4':
            family_form.base_fields[fname].required = True

    elif not value['required']:
        # name is actual name plus : plus a number
        # split up to name and number
        bits = name.split(':')
        fname = bits[0]
        formnum = bits[1]
        if formnum == '1':
            student_form.base_fields[fname].required = False
        elif formnum == '2':
            mother_form.fields[fname].required = False
        elif formnum == '3':
            father_form.fields[fname].required = False
        elif formnum == '4':
            family_form.base_fields[fname].required = False
```

I tried base_fields which kind of worked but was a bit messy.

Any ideas?

Comment: The first argument to a form should be data, so I would expect `StudentDetailForm(data=request.POST or None)` - it's not clear why you have `StudentDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None)`.

Comment: It seems to be fine in other places. I don't see any issues..yet

Comment: What is `webfields`? and what does `webfields.items()` return?

Comment: You must have done something like overriding `__init__` in `MyForm`. Otherwise `StudentDetailForm(None, data=request.POST or None)` would raise `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'data'`.

Comment: It's a dic of all the fields with a visible or required value associated with them. Then I go through them and delete the ones that are not set to visible. The changing the required value is the problem. When I submit them their values seem to change.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *When I submit them their values seem to change*. I don't think I can offer you specific advice for your view, it's too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to change `base_fields` - that updates the fields of the `StudentDetailForm` class, not just the particular `form` instance

Depending on the rest of your view, setting `form.fields['first_name'].required` should work.

However, it's normally better to set `self.fields['first_name'].required` inside the form's `__init__` method. I'm not sure how you would do this because you seem to have multiple forms and many field names, so here's a simpler example.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        first_name_required = kwargs.pop('first_name_required')
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].required = first_name_required
```

You would then initialise your form like:

```
form = MyForm(data=request.POST, first_name_required=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This is more of my code. I think the __init__ is the right track, just not too sure how to do it.

Comment: I've given a simple example of the `__init__` method, hopefully you can apply it to your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try that now. I'm trying to make it quite dynamic. Would this work for many fields?

Comment: It all works fine until I submit the form. Then some ones that say are required are not and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, you could add more arguments to the `__init__` method if required (or perhaps a list of required fields).

Comment: I'm not sure why you are getting *some ones that say are required are not and vice versa*. I've tested my example and it works.

Comment: I think I'm about to crack it. I just get a keyerror on 'first_name_required'

Comment: If you have `kwargs.pop('first_name_required')`, then you **must** include `first_name_required` when instantiating the form, e.g. `MyForm(data=request.POST, first_name_required=True)`. If you forget to include it, e.g. `MyForm(data=request.POST)`, then you'll get a `KeyError`. You could provide a default, e.g. `kwargs.pop('first_name_required', False)`, however doing this might hide faulty code.